Making a token on the mainnet; A few questions before I hit enter on the mint command(CLI)
This is that command; spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCX(censored) create-token --transfer-fee 300 300000 --decimals 10 --enable-metadata --enable-group --metadata-address TWZ2Knp2sctRH3yXrsP2SNvaPfFzUcz(censored)
question 1) the phantom wallet account says it's solana address is, 14fbryUnN5Px4GGg1MMgTKawpyvBXUzk4p8(censored)  these address dont match but, yet when I put in the seedphrase on the recover command for the 14fb address it says I'm recovering the TWZ2k address so I guess they are the same?? under the meta address mint option do I use the one I copy and paste from the wallet or the one I get from that CLI recovery confirmation?
question 2) Is there any other token 2022 extensions I can add? Since I'm using real money now to mint this, I wanna make sure I include important ones for the sake of governance, part of this tokens economy is the ability to change aspects through voting etc. I'm assuming I can change transfer fees later. As well as whatever attributes I add through "extensions"
question 3) what's the best way to change the meta data? Since I enabled the metadata ooption in CLI can I just POINT to a uri on akord that holds my json file? cause I made my json file fancy like the old ones in the github(archive) with tags, descriptions, website links etc.

To answer your questions:
1: If you want to create the token at address TWZ2k, you need to pass that keypair into create-token, ie: spl-token create-token <ARGS> TWZ2K-keypair.json
2: It's up to you, all the extensions are available to browse at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions, but those should be enough. Depending on your use-case, the "permanent delegate" to be able to seize tokens from anyone might be useful for governance.
3: The metadata in the mint does have a URI field, so yep, you can just point that at your fancy JSON hosted somewhere. I can't guarantee how it'll be displayed by websites and such, but you can always modify that JSON. If you want to change the metadata in the mint, you can just do spl-token update-metadata ... https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#example-update-a-field
